# How can I include only rows which satisfy a certain condition when calculating a mean?

Tags: r

I'm very new to R so this is quite basic but have hit a brick wall!

Basically, I am trying to calculate the mean but I only want to include rows where a certain condition is satisfied. The column has levels 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 only. I would only like to include rows where the data in this column is 2 or 3.

Thank you from a very confused student who is very new to R!!

Comment: Try: `y[y$x %in% c(2,3),]` or if it is a vector `x[x %in% c(2,3)]` or `x[x>=2 & x <=3]`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the data when you use the mean function:

```
# df: the data.frame you're using
# columnToFilter: column you are going to filter
# columnToMean: column which you're calculating the mean
mean(df[df$columnFitler %in% c(2,3), ]$columnToMean)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Appreciated